# Progress bar showing a 25% completion initially

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a progress bar in WinForms which displays the progress of an uploading activity. I have set the following properties for the progress bar:

```
MarqueePercentage = 25
MarqueeStep = 1
MarqueeSpeed = 30
Maximum = 100
```

The problem is that the progress bar fills up to 25% and then gets cleared and starts from the beginning. I am using chilkat sftp component to do the upload.

Comment: Can you give an example of your code?

Comment: The Winforms ProgressBar control doesn't have properties like that.  Best place to find help is the vendor's support forum.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/progress/ProgressODoom.aspx ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to start at MarqueeStep = 0